# How to use BaseHTTPServer to serve a form in a self-contained server?

Tags: python, web

I have a simple web server based on `BaseHTTPServer` which processes `GET` requests (I reuse a previous example below). I would like, for a particular GET parameter (`x` in the example below), to open a web page with a simple form and a submit button.

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs

class GetHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        url = urlparse(self.path)
        d = parse_qs(url[4])
        if 'x' in d:
            self.handle_input_form()  # this is the part I want to write
        else:
            if 'c' in d:
                print d['c'][0]
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
        return

    def handle_input_form(self):
        # here a form is displayed, user can input something, submit and 
        # the content this is handled back to the script for processing
        # the next three lines are just a place holder
        pass
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), GetHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

In other words, this is a self-contained web server (no cgi pages) which I want to keep as simple as possible. I saw [a great example of how to use CGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448837/how-do-i-create-a-webpage-with-buttons-that-invoke-various-python-scripts-on-the) together with the documentation pages, but all assume that there will be a classical cgi-bin structure.
Is what I am trying to achieve easy in Python (I am sure it is possible :))?

I would appreciate very much a general answer on best practices (*"do it like that"* or *"don't do it like that"* - please keep in mind this is an internal, private server which will not run anything important) as well as the overall flow of `handle_input_form()`.

---

**EDIT**: Following up on [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements)' suggestion I used [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/) and adapted [the example in the tutorial](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#html-form-handling):

```
import bottle

@bottle.get('/note') # or @route('/note')
def note():
    return '''
        <form action="/note" method="post">
            <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="note">
            Some initial text, if needed
            </textarea>
            <input value="submit" type="submit" />
        </form>
    '''

@bottle.post('/note') # or @route('/note', method='POST')
def note_update():
    note = bottle.request.forms.get('note')
    # processing the content of the text frame here
```

Comment: Best practices - use `flask`/`bottle` for something like this? Then you'll find extending it easier and most of this already handled for you?

Comment: @JonClements: Thanks - this is exactly what I needed. I had it working within a few minutes using the provided examples (I used Bottle). Can you please make it an answer so that I can accept it? (I will edit my question to add the few lines of code which solve the problem)

Comment: CW "answer" added - you may wish to edit that to include your code instead. Best practice answers generally aren't in topic for SO but should make an okay Q&A pair for future visitors wanting something simple and also starting by looking at the builtin HttpServer

Comment: This is "best practice" + actual solution afterwards :) I will update my question with the solution. I actually rewrote my server with Bottle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something this simple that's also scalable you're better off using a micro-framework such as `flask` or `bottle`.