# Passing variables from Javascript to a Python script

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am trying to use Javascript to call a Python script. Also, I must pass variables to the Python script from my Javascript. Once the result is returned in Python, I want to pass this result back to Javascript. I am not sure what the best way to do this is.

I have seen various implementations with flask and json, but I am confused by which would be the best way to do this.

To give an example, this is what I am trying to do:

**Javascript.js**

```
myJSVariable1 = “Hello “

myJSVariable2 = “World!” 

result = callPythonScript(myJSVariable1, myJSVariable2)

console.log(result)
```

**pythonScript.py**

```
print(myJSVariable1, myJSVariable2)
```

In this example, I would expect that console.log(result) return “Hello World!” as pythonScript.py prints the result of myJSVariable1 concatenated with myJSVariable2.

Does anyone have any recommendations for doing something like this?

Comment: Why is this tagged `json`?

Comment: Why are you doing this? And in what context? Will it be running on a server with large amounts of data passed between the two, or is it literally just a one-off simple hello world ?

Comment: You are literally asking to do something like execute python code from inside a js module.  You could pass the arguments on the command line, execute the python code via your OS, and process the returned value.  On the python side, you'd parse the command line arguments, call the function, and write to STDOUT. 

What you are probably really asking to do is to calling a server side python function from inside the browser. In that case it's a possible duplicate of [Run Python script from AJAX or JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336688/run-python-script-from-ajax-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Variables are a concept that is intimately tied to a single programming language, and in fact even a single programming language implementation. Passing variables between programming languages and even between different implementations of the *same* programming language is usually impossible, unless those implementations have been *specifically* written to allow for such a *polyglot programming* style.

There are four programming language implementation frameworks I am aware of that are explicitly designed to allow for programming language implementations to be written in such a way that they support polyglot programming:

- [Parrot](http://parrot.org/)
- [Rubinius](https://rubinius.com/)
- [Dynamic Language Runtime](https://github.com/IronLanguages/dlr)
- [Truffle](https://github.com/oracle/graal/tree/master/truffle)

However, it seems that, unfortunately, none of those has both a production-quality Python and ECMAScript implementation:

- Parrot is abandoned, there has not been a release since 2016-02-16 and no commit since 2017-10-02.

  - Also, none of the Python implementations for Parrot were ever even close to production-ready:
  - [Pynie](https://bitbucket.org/allison/pynie/)
  - [Pirate](http://web.archive.org/web/20100923213256/http://pirate.tangentcode.com/)
  - [pie-thon](http://www.sidhe.org/~dan/blog/archives/000371.html)
  - The same is true of the ECMAScript implementations for Parrot:
  - [Parrot/ecmascript](https://github.com/parrot/ecmascript)
  - PJS
- On Rubinius, at the moment, no language implementation except Ruby is production-ready:

  - [Typhon](http://vic.github.io/typhon/)
  - [Tofu](https://github.com/brixen/tofu) (ECMAScript implementation; you will notice that nothing except the README was ever written)
- A stripped down, frozen version of the DLR is shipped as part of .NET, but Microsoft itself has abandoned it. [It is still being developed](https://github.com/IronLanguages/dlr) as part of the [IronLanguages](https://github.com/IronLanguages) project, though.

  - [IronPython](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2) is a mature, production-ready implementation of Python 2 on the DLR, however [Python 3 support](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3) is not production-ready yet.
  - Unfortunately, all ECMAScript implementations on the DLR have been abandoned:
  - Managed JScript was an official ECMAScript implementation by Microsoft, which was intended to be one of the poster childs for the DLR, but it was never published and has long since been abandoned.
  - [IronJS](https://ironjs.wordpress.com/) is abandoned.
- Truffle is actively maintained, actively developed, and production-ready.

  - [GraalJS](https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs) is actively maintained, actively developed, and production-ready.
  - Unfortunately, both Python implementations for Truffle are currently still in development:
  - [GraalPython](https://github.com/graalvm/graalpython)
  - [ZipPy](https://github.com/securesystemslab/zippy)

So, as you can see, while there are some polyglot programming language implementation frameworks, and there are some Python and ECMAScript implementations for those frameworks, there is unfortunately not a single framework which has production-ready implementations of both Python and ECMAScript: DLR has Python (2) but not ECMAScript, Truffle has ECMAScript but not Python.

However, there is another problem with your idea of passing variables: neither Python nor ECMAScript reify variables, IOW, variables are not objects (or primitives) in those languages. And you can only pass *values*, i.e. objects and primitives.