# WSGI Web frontend (using jquery, AJAX, css) for python backend

Tags: python, ajax, user-interface, wsgi

Disclaimer: I am new to python but have coded in Drupal where I used ajax, jquery, json

I need to create a simple web app front-end (using jquery, AJAX, css) for my python backend. I successfully followed the instructions on this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336866/how-to-implement-a-minimal-server-for-ajax-in-python) page, but the WSGI-served html refuses to load my html's stylesheets and jquery.js. In the previously mentioned link, S.Lott wrote, "The demo_app is relatively easy to write; it handles your Ajax requests." I (believe that I) understand the demo_app and much of his "WSGI implementation," but obviously not enough. I'm happy to research the answer but need a nudge in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are you using wsgi directly? If it's just for edification, that's fine, if not, you might want to read PEP 0333 http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/. Specifically this section:  "this should not be construed to mean that application developers will use WSGI as a web programming API! It is assumed that application developers will continue to use existing, high-level framework services to develop their applications. WSGI is a tool for framework and server developers, and is not intended to directly support application developers."

Comment: If you're looking to just get a website up and running quickly with python, I would look in to flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) is an interface between the webserver (like Apache) and your Python web application. It provides a standard way of running Python code on web servers.

You do not need WSGI to serve static files like JavaScript or CSS (because JS/CSS is not a Python code). Configure your web server to serve static files in a *normal* way, apart of your WSGI-based Python web application.

With Apache [typical solution](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Mounting_At_Root_Of_Site) is to use `Alias` directive:

```
Alias /media/ /usr/local/www/documents/media/              # Static files, e.g. http://example.com/media
WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi   # WSGI app mounted at the root of site, e.g. http://example.com
```

Comment: Thank you. After reading "You'll be reinventing quite a few wheels if you work at such a low level of abstraction. Have you considered using a web framework?" from http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-February/1265524.html, I think I need to install Django, since my project will involve processing LOTS of scripts. Thank you!

Comment: There are other frameworks too: http://www.wsgi.org/en/latest/frameworks.html, however Django has really great community and lot of docs.